# CSS - Make text fit to div width and be responsive

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I want a picture responsive to the change in page-width and with that picture a text matching the pictures width without breaking into two lines and always filling out the div width.

I can't figure this out.
I have created this Plunker to illustrate my problem:
[Plunker - Make text fit to div](https://plnkr.co/edit/fukrYC7nIH9DL1QkZenm?p=preview)

How can I make the text re-size to fit the picture width?
I know have set font-size with vw in an attempt to make it scale, but this also make it very small when the page is shown i a phone, for example.

Please, can I get some help in how to make this work.

Plunker code:

HTML:

```
<body>

<p class="spacer"></p>

<img class="img-responsive page-pic" src="https://placehold.it/800x300" />
<h3 class="page-pic-text">
  abcdefghijklmnopq abc abcdefghijklmn
</h3>
<h1 class="page-text">
  Abcdefghi, abc abc abcde abcde!
</h1>
<BR />
<BR />
<BR />
<BR />
<BR />
<BR />
<h3>How to make the first and second text to match the pictures width?</h3>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.spacer {
  height: 60px;
}

.page-pic {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 35%;
    min-width: 260px;
}

.page-pic-text {
    font-family: Futura, 'Trebuchet MS', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 130%;
    font-size: 1.357vw;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    font-weight: 500;
    letter-spacing: 0.3em;
    margin: 1% auto;
    width: 35%;
    min-width: 260px;
    text-align: center;
}

.page-text {
    font-family: TimesNewRoman, 'Times New Roman', Times, Baskerville, Georgia, serif;
    font-size: 150%;
    font-size: 2.2vw;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-weight: 200;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    margin: 0% auto;
    padding-top: 3%;
    width: 35%;
    min-width: 260px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want? Change the width and height as you need. I have used inline css. If you want to use external css and hope that your bootstrap is working properly. I have used offline bootstrap, so do not want to pay your attention on that. Just check the html.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>working with bootstrap offline</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">

  <style type="text/css">
    body{
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
    }

    .page-pic-text {
      font-family: Futura, 'Trebuchet MS', Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 130%;
      font-size: 1.357vw;
    font-style: normal;
      font-variant: small-caps;
      font-weight: 500;
      letter-spacing: 0.3em;
      margin: 1% auto;
      width: 35%;
      min-width: 260px;
      text-align: center;
    }

  </style>

</head>
<body>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="img-responsive" style="width:50%;height:50%;">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1a/Bachalpseeflowers.jpg" style="width:100%;height:100%;">
      <h2 class="page-pic-text" style=""> is this what you want</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>



</html>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but that does not do what I want. In your example the text "is this what you want" does not become large enough to cover the hole length of the picture. I want that text to re-size to match the width of the picture.

Comment: I have tested it in this plunker: [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/mlekA5UPlmKiK7Z4pqiO?p=preview) and the text have constant size when the browser width is changed.

Comment: what about the image, is it fit for your need.I'll check for tht text

Comment: The image is not a problem, I can make the image behave like I want. But the text does still not re-size to fit the image width. Now you are just using my CSS and that is not working ...

Answer (score -1):

Simple answer: it's not possible without javascript.

Comment: Maybe, I don't know. How can you solve it with JavaScript?

Comment: I don't understand the down vote, he asked for a css method and I gave the correct answer.

Comment: @JohnMaster you can use jquery plugins like http://fittextjs.com or write your own js that calculates the font-size required to make the text a specific width.

Comment: @JohnMaster there is also a fittext version on github made by someone else that does not require jQuery.

Comment: Images is a matter of using percentages as width. Keep in mind that the image parent element width should be 100% if you want the image width in percentage relative to the viewport.

Comment: I'm sorry to say that I can't get fittext.js to work. Sure it squeezes short strings to fit but for my text "abcdefghijklmnopq abc abcdefghijklmn" it breaks it into three lines of text and I need it to be one line.

Comment: @JohnMaster add the following css: ``white-space: nowrap;``